# Question relate to pass by reference in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *addXX(char *B);

int main(void) {
  char str1[25], *str2;
  gets(str1);
  str2=addXX(str1);
  puts(str2);
  exit(0);
}
char *addXX(char *B) {
  strcat(B,"XX");
  return (B);
}
```

This is the note I got from my class, which shows how call by reference works in C. However, there is one thing I don't understand. In the `*addXX` function, we passed `str1` into the function, which is also the memory address since it's an array name. Then we store the `str1` memory address into pointer `char*B`, but we don't add `*` in front B when we use `B` in the function.  This is the part I don't understand, why we should not use `*B` instead `B`?

Can anyone explain it to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the `*addXX` function, we passed `str1` into the function,
>   which is also the memory address since it's an array name. Then we
>   store the `str1` memory address into pointer `char*B`, but we
>   don't add `*` in front B when we use `B` in the function. 
>   This is the part I don't understand, why we should not use `*B`
>   instead `B`?

Inside the function you use `B` twice,

```
char *addXX(char *B) {
  strcat(B,"XX");
  return (B);
}
```

First, in

```
strcat(B,"XX");
```

you use `B` instead of `*B` because `strcat()` expects a pointer as the first argument.

The same goes for the second time it is used,

```
return (B);
```

You declared the function `*addXX` that returns a pointer to char, hence, you need to return the pointer and not dereference it.

So, all your reasoning is good. But since the function expects a pointer, you don't have to dereference it.

### Just a comment,

what you are doing is passing by address, meaning that you pass the address of a variable to the function `*addXX`. Passing by reference is a different thing and there's no passing by reference in C.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation! By the way, it's the same thing when I use ```return(B)```, since I declared the function which passes the pointer, So I have to return a pointer too right?

Comment: exactly, I added that as well to the answer :) I'm glad it helped.